# No easy way to edit roles on an added scope

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

We are using carbon for adding roles and assigning to user accounts. In publisher when adding scopes to our api endpoints we can add roles to the scope.

When it comes to adding further roles you can't select an existing scope and edit the roles list further, it seems you have to delete the scope and start over again, maintaining any previously added roles when adding new ones in.

There is only a trash bin icon next to each scope added above the list of api endpoints, no edit icon of any sort.

Is this by design, or is there a way to edit existing scope details that we have not seen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, this is by design and reported as a possible [improvement](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4314). You have to delete and recreate scopes.